# Apple Mail reply arrow not working reliably

Tags: macos, mail.app, exchange-activesync

I'm running Lion, connecting to an Exchange 2010 server. Sent messages are stored locally.

Once I've replied to a messages in my Inbox, the "replied" arrow appears to the left of the message, as normal.  But when I click on the arrow to see the actual reply it fails roughly 50% of the time. By "fails" I mean that nothing comes up when I click.  A message I sent minutes earlier/later can work just fine.

The reply WAS sent using Apple Mail (not my iPhone) and it IS in my sent mail folder.  I have re-built my Spotlight index.

Comment: Fat finger: "the ARROW" appears to the left ...

Comment: You can easily edit your own posts by clicking the [edit](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/20670/edit) link right underneath the question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the issue is that Microsoft doesn't provide the Active Sync API to anything other than mobile devices. This is why using Exchange on Mac is a bit buggy.

I would recommend using Microsoft's own Outlook Web App (OWA) for your Exchange emails. Or installing the actual Outlook program for your computer. Those are what I use. :)

Those are probably your two best options if you need your email to be 100% reliable on your Mac.

Comment: Oops looks like I revived an old thread. For some reason, this was on the main page. Haha sorry. I'll keep my post though incase anyone else finds it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same thing, but only with my company's Exchange server. My other IMAP servers (Gmail, MobileMe a private IMAP) all work fine, 100% of the time.

I'm pretty sure this is a server side Exchange bug.

Comment: Or possibly a confusion between server sided <sent items> and the local <sent> folder.  Not sure.  But we have 100's of Mac users converting to Lion/Exchange 2010 and this will be an issue

Comment: i think it has to do with the general activity of the Exchange Server maybe the Server reaches it's limits.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same behavior with IMAP accounts in Mail under Lion. I think it's a general bug, and not limited to Exchange (I say this because I have no Exchange accounts).

Comment: I saw something similar with Mail pre-lion, but completely re-building my accounts solved the problem.  I'm wondering if Lion introduced the issue.